# What is this "union"?

Tags: category-theory

[image]

The book is Cisinski HCHA 2019.

The notation suggests that that image does not depend on $X$ and $T$, does it?

Comment: Isn't $Y \cup Z$ just notation for the image of the morphism $Y \amalg_X Z \to T$? At least, that's what the remark seems to say.

Answer (score 1):

That is true, as you can recover $X$ as the pullback of the cospan $Y\to T \leftarrow Z$.